# Как отменить сжатие блока?

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы блок с картинкой не сжимался на маленьких разрешениях, а сжимался только блок с формой? А то у меня получается вот так

jsfiddle.net/u87hjon5/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно сделать ширину блока с фото фиксированной с помощью `width` или же `min-width`.

Я бы посоветовал вам сделать `div.wrapper` фиксированной ширины до определённой ширины экрана (`>960px`, например), а после (от `0` до `960px`) - преобразовать форму так, чтобы она не страдала от сужения картинки. Я бы посоветовал либо убрать картинку вообще, либо уменьшить её высоту и расположить форму под ней.

Comment: а есть способ без фиксированной ширины? И max-width тут не нужна, я же не увеличиваю блок, а уменьшаю

Comment: Опечатка, исправил на `min-width`.
В CSS ширина элемента либо зависит от ширины чего-то другого, либо фиксированная. В вашем случае больше подходит фиксированная.

Comment: теперь при уменьшении размера экрана обрезается фоновое изображение

Comment: Так будет в любом случае. Поэтому я вам сказал сделать ширину картинки фиксированной до определённой ширины экрана, а дальше адаптивной.